# Can I have one Azure Dev release pipeline that does PR releases to different environments based on the target branch of the PR?

Tags: azure-devops, git-flow

I've been fighting with this for a while.   I've been able to get it working with two separate release pipelines, but not with one.   It seems that in one pipeline the PR trigger for releases fires for all environments, even with separate build artifacts.

Goal is to have the following in one release pipeline:

PR to dev and merge to dev deploys to dev environment

PR to main deploys to QA environment

Merge to main of said PR releases to prod (with manual approval step).

It would be great to get this one one release pipeline, as that would reduce overhead and management, etc.

I've tried all sorts of variations with artifact release triggers and the environment pre-deployment conditions, but to no avail.

I've even tried using 2 separate build pipelines (one for main, one for develop) and then loading both as artifacts and trying to separate that way, but even when only 1 build pipeline runs, it triggers the PR release condition for both environments.

Comment: A PR being deployed to a static environment doesn't really make sense. Different PRs are going to deploy on top of each other, or even have race conditions where multiple PRs are attempting to deploy at the same time. If you want PRs to deploy, design your deployment process to stand up an ephemeral environment that can be easily torn down when the PR is closed.

Comment: Are you using classic releases or the newer pipelines?

Comment: while I agree a ephemeral env stood up would be better, I disagree that PRs going to static environments have no value.

Comment: Using the releases, which I believe is "classic".   you can view the yml, but not edit it directly.   We're using Yyml based build pipelines.   I believe you can put release steps into those now, which may be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this if you implement your release pipeline with the new YAML pipelines.

The simplest option (which is not quite what you are asking for but should get the same outcome) would be to create a [template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) with your core deployment logic, then create separate pipelines that reuse this template. That should allow you to replicate the triggers that you already had working for two release pipelines without needing to duplicate the deployment code.

Alternatively, you could set up a single YAML pipeline with Stages for Dev, QA and Prod, and set [conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) on the stages, based on the source branch and/or build reason.

Comment: very cool, will give it a try.   thanks!